# File upload does not return files within bootstrap modal using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

When I save, the controller does not receive the file of the form but the other file format still receives.

Here's my view code:

```html
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="label-control col-md-3">Customer Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="txtCustomerName" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mail" class="label-control col-md-3">Customer Mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="txtCustomerMail" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="label-control col-md-3">Customer Phone</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="txtCustomerPhone" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image" class="label-control col-md-3">Customer Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="file" name="fileCustomerImage" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form?

Comment: `public function addCustomer()
    {
        $customer_name = $this->input->post('txtCustomerName');
        $customer_mail = $this->input->post('txtCustomerMail');
        $customer_phone = $this->input->post('txtCustomerPhone');
        $customer_image = $this->upload_image('fileCustomerImage');
        
        $add = $this->ion_auth->addCustomer($customer_name, $customer_mail, $customer_phone, $customer_image);

        $msg['success'] = false;
        if($add){
            $msg['success'] = true;
        }
        echo json_encode($msg);  
    }`